# How can I parse the certificate information output from the security command in Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, keychain

I need to retrieve the attributes of a certificate that is stored in the keychain on my Mac from the command line. I can collect them manually from the Keychain Access app, but I want to do that with a script.

[image]

I used the `security` command to get a certificate and "grep" to inspect the "subject" section:

```
security find-certificate -c "Apple Development" login.keychain | grep "subj"
```

and then got the following output (some omitted by "...").

```
"subj"<blob>=0x3081943...553  "0\201\2241\0320\03...02US"
```

In the output above, what format is the data following `"subj"<blob>=` and how can I parse it? I found that decoding the first half of the hexadecimal sequence(0x30...) with UTF-8 yields the second half of the string (0\201...), but I don't know what `0\201\2241\...` means. I have tried other character codes, but they just give me garbled characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the format, the certificates are stored in DER/PEM format, which is a representation of ASN.1 encoded data. What you see in the output is the hexadecimal representation of the ASN.1 binary data. The blob indicates that the value or attribute is stored as binary data.

As for exporting (for certificates), I would highly recommend combining `security` with `openssl` as follows:

```
security find certificate -p -c "Apple Development" login.keychain | openssl x509 -noout -subject
```

The `-p` option in the security command exports the found certificate in PEM format, which is something openssl can use. You can then pipe the PEM data into the `openssl` command, where one can easily extract the subject using the `-subject` option.

You can check out both the [man page of security](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/security/) and the [man page of openssl x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html).

Comment: I believe `find certificate` should be hyphenated: `find-certificate`. At least that's the case in macOS 13.6.2; not sure about other macOS versions.

Comment: You are correct, the `-p` option is only available for the `find-certificate` option as well